# embed XSL source node in ad hoc css

Tags: css, xslt

I have this XSL source node:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Colour"/>  -->  #00FF00
```

And what I basically want to accomplish is this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Collection/DVD">
  <tr style="background-color: #00FF00;">
  ...
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I've tried this:

```
<xsl:text>&lt;tr style=&quot;background-color: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Colour"/><xsl:text>;&quot;&gt;</xsl:text>
```

But then the <tr gets actually outputted in the browser.

I cannot do this either:

```
<xsl:text><tr style="background-color: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Colour"/><xsl:text>;"></xsl:text>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Please add more information. 1) your source XML, 2) your full stylesheet (or at least the full relevant templates if it is very big), your desired result. There is not enough information.

Comment: `value-of` select is not a variable. It's a value from a source node.

Comment: `xsl:value-of` is not a variable. `xsl:variable` is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xsl:attribute` for this attribute.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Collection/DVD">
  <tr>
     <xsl:attribute name="style">
     <xsl:text>background-color: </xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="Colour"/>
     <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:attribute>
  <!--...-->
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You might need to adjust this solution slightly - depending on your input XML. As it is now, it will only work if a `DVD` element has a child element `Colour` in your input.

Note that `xsl:value-of` is *not* a variable in XSLT. It is used to *select* nodes.